# Is there a better way to write this nested map in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, filter, reduce

I'm embarrassed to post this but I could really use a hand here. This code just looks nasty. I have a feeling that I can write a cleaner approach with `filter` or `reduce` but can't seem to stab it. Any thoughts, community?

```
const vin = detections.map(detection => {
    return detection.textAnnotations.map(v => {
        let n = v.description.replace(/\s+/g, '');
        if (n.length === 17) {
            return n;
        }
    });
})[0][0];
```

Thanks!

Comment: Well, for starters, don't be embarrassed to post code or you won't be able to improve with input from the community!

Comment: This belongs in https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Why the two `.map`s? Why not just select the first `detection` and the first `textAnnotations` inside it, then replace appropriately, without any looping at all?

Comment: @NikKyriakides Actually, this question should not be asked even at CR: https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask and https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic. It doesn't tick most of the boxes. But well, let OP ask it there, let's see what happens...

Comment: @GerardoFurtado I insist

Comment: Can you describe what this piece of code is supposed to do? Right now it seems that mapping is redundant, as CertainPerformance said. Especially, is `undefined` really what you want, if `n.length` is not 17?

Comment: Can you please add detections value and expected result

Answer (score 0):

Just an attempt to refactor your code:

```
const getMatchedTextAnnotation = (textAnnotation) => {
    const n = textAnnotation.description.replace(/\s+/g, '');
    return n.length === 17 ? n : null;
}

const extractAnnotationsFromDetection = (detection) => {
    return detection.textAnnotations.reduce((arr, textAnnotation) => {
        const n = getMatchedTextAnnotation(textAnnotation);
        return !!n ? [ ...arr, n] : arr;
    }, [])
}

const vinArr = detections.reduce((arr, detection) => {
    const subArr = extractAnnotationsFromDetection(detection);
    return !!subArr ? [ ...arr, ...subArr ] : arr;
}, [])

const vin = !!vinArr ? vinArr[0] : null;
```

Comment: I don't see how this makes it better.